# .Net Socket Read function blocking issue

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, network-programming

I have client-server application in C#.Net and for that I am using Tcp Socket. I have used following function to aggressive close of socket object.

```
void CloseSocket(Socket socket)
{
      if(socket != null)
      {
           socket.ShutDown(ocketShutdown.Both);
           socket.Close();
      } 
}
```

In Normal Condition this function works perfectly and my method returns with 0 bytes returned from Read function.

**But whenever client process terminated by taskmanager server program blocks into read function of network stream.**

How can I workaround this read blocking function ? I don't want to use AsyncRead function because whole project uses blocking strategy so write now I can't change it to Async pattern.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify: is the problem that the *code you have posted* blocks? Or are you saying that the read code (not shown) doesn't detect zombie connections?

Comment: Could you post the code you use for receive? I'd expect an exception about a blocking operation being interrupted in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm *assuming* that what you are saying is that when the connection isn't closed cleanly by the client, the server can end up blocking at `Read` indefinitely, even if the client has actually terminated abruptly. If so: yes, that happens. So if you want to use the synchronous read methods, you should use timeouts, in particular [`ReceiveTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout.aspx). If you have a multi-message protocol, it may be worthwhile adding some kind of heartbeat message periodically, to allow you to correctly identify true zombies from idle connections (for example: if you are sending a heartbeat every minute, and you haven't seen any activity on a connection for 3 minutes, hit it with a shovel).

Comment: Shouldn't closing the socket interrupt the block though?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis my understanding is that he is killing the client, so that his code snippet never runs. A different questions is why killing a process does not terminate/RST the TCP connection which it should.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis do you mean in a regular "sweep" thread that checks the last activity? if so, yes, that would probably also result in some detectable exit condition on the thread that is calling `Receive` / `Read`

Comment: @usr Honestly, I never rely on sockets closing properly. Because in the real world: they don't. Especially when you have lots of moving parts (tunnels/VPNs, load-balancers, relays, etc) between the two ends.

Comment: @MarcGravell I meant when there is a blocking `Receive()` method and you `Close()` the socket from another thread, an exception "A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall" is usually thrown. I think @usr is on to something though.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis see also my reply to usr

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't think a receive timeout is a bad idea, but if you can `Close()` a socket while another thread keeps blocking on it I really should start fixing my code :s

Comment: @C.Evenhuis in the problematic scenario, `Close()` was never called - simply: the socket got broken. Killing a process, yanking a cable (power or network), etc - or just general badness. But : dead sockets that break without notifying the other end are a real thing.

Comment: @MarcGravell "I have used following function to aggressive close of socket object." that line made me assume it _was_ called.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis "But whenever client process terminated by taskmanager" - if you kill a process, lots of things get skipped

Answer (score 1):

```
**you can try this may help you**


    public void close()
        {
            if(clientSocket != null )
            {
                sendCommand("QUIT");
            }

            cleanup();

        }

    private void cleanup()
        {
            if(clientSocket!=null)
            {
                clientSocket.Close();
                clientSocket = null;
            }
            logined = false;
        }
```

Comment: Sending a `QUIT` message would depend a lot on that being sensible to the protocol...

Comment: while process is terminated by taskmanager it will not harm any thing regardless quit out the session.